# How to update device attributes with thingsboard Iot gateway

Tags: iot, gateway, thingsboard

I'd like to update attributes from the device using Thingsboard IoT Gateway, but it will not work.

Thingsboard 1.4.0
Thingsboard IoT Gateway 1.2
Mosqquito(Broker)
Node.js(Client)

It all starts up and calls the attribute update API of the device, but the Gateway log does not appear and it does not seem to have arrived.

---

Client ->(OK) Mosqquito ->(??? no log) Gateway -> Thingsboard

---

mqtt-config.json uses this as it is.
https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard-gateway/blob/master/src/main/resources/mqtt-config.json

teremetoryAPI is working (value has been updated as seen in Console)
Please tell me what settings should be made to update the attributes of the device.

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt');
var os = require("os");
require('date-utils');
var device = 'T-001';

const thingsboardHost = "mqtt://127.0.0.1:1883";

console.log('Connecting to: %s', thingsboardHost);
var client  = mqtt.connect(thingsboardHost, {
    will: {topic: device + '/disconnect', payload: '', qos: 1}
});

var appState;

client.on('connect', function () {
    publish(device + '/connect', "");
    console.log('Client connected!');

    // teremetory OK
    publish('sensor/' + device + '/temperature', JSON.stringify({"firmware_version":"1.0.2", "value":"37.7"}));

    // attribute NG ?????
    publish("sensor/" + device + "/appState", JSON.stringify({"appState":"123"}));
});

client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
    console.log('Received attribute topic: %s, message: %s', topic, message.toString());
})

function publish (topic, json) {
    client.publish(topic, json);
    console.log('Client publish. topic[' + topic + "] [" + json + "]");
}
```

Comment: I solved. Thank you very much.

Comment: please add how you solve your issue on the answer, you can help someone with the same problem.